# Exception : EntityFramework Core exception on UseSqlServer

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this code :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
  base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

  optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString"); //Exception here
}
```

At runtime I get an exception :

> *Error CS0012: The type 'DBConenction' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 
>   'System.Data.Common, version=4.1.0.0*

I tried to upgrade all packages, add a reference to System.Data.Common 4.1.0.0 I tried higher version too with the same result. I tried with .NET Core 2.0 finalpreview1 I get the same problem. I tried several solution found on the web but without success.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by 'installed System.Data.Common 4.1.0.0 and higher'? Did you add a reference?

Comment: Yes I rephrased my post.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall EntityFramework via NuGet manager?

Comment: Have you referred EF where in your client project . (eg Refer EF in web api or mvc)

Comment: I have seen some unexpected issues similar to this. A few things that have helped at different times: 
1. Make sure you are not mixing nuget.org and pre-release nuget feeds
2. Clean the package cache. You can do this in Visual Studio settings or from the command line with nuget.exe locals all -clear
3. Delete the %userprofile%\.dotnet folder and then restore the dependencies on the application

Comment: I re-read your post and I noticed "DBConenction" contains two typos. Can you confirm that you introduced the typos when you transcribed the exception and that the original exception refers to "DbConnection"?

Comment: Also, consider creating an issue in https://github.com/aspnet/entityframework/issues, but please attach a project that reproduces the issue. There are lots of details missing here, including what platform your application targets.

Comment: Hey Diego, he and i went back and forth. He sent me a repo that caused the failure on 3 machines on his end but 0 on mine. We went over netfx versions, dotnet versions, dotnet sdk version etc etc before I reached out to you. Your responses above were really helpful. He did send me another email yesterday saying that after rebuilding his dev environment he *thinks* the discriminator is ...CodeRush! We'll see.... I've tweeted him to update us here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Read the following documentation and be sure to install all the packages mentioned:

[Microsoft EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)